# Simple class to let a thread make a clean work

Tags: c#

I was working on the last days with threads and I didn't want to use ugly methods like `Abort()`, etc.

So I did a simple class which does use one of the most performant and better alternative to `Abort()`. The class is named as `CThread.cs` which would stand for `CleanThread.cs`.

Class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CThread
{
    public List<CancellationTokenSource> CreatedThreads = new List<CancellationTokenSource>();

    private void MyFunction(Action callback, bool inLoop, int currentIndex)
    {
        if (inLoop)
        {
            while (!CreatedThreads[currentIndex].IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                callback();
            }
        }
        else { callback(); }
    }

    private int getLastIndex()
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (CancellationTokenSource item in CreatedThreads)
        {
            ++index;
        }

        return (index - 1);
    }

    public new void Start(Action callback, bool inLoop)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        CreatedThreads.Add(tokenSource);
        int currentIndex = getLastIndex();
        Task task = Task.Run(() => MyFunction(callback, inLoop, currentIndex)); // use Task.Factory.StartNew for .net 4.0
    }

    public new void Stop(int threadIndex)
    {
        CreatedThreads[threadIndex].Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread has been stopped successfully! Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

and finally, how I use it:

```
using System;

namespace CThreadExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void printFunction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CThread myThread = new CThread();
            myThread.Start(printFunction, true);

            // when the user presses any key the thread will be stopped
            Console.ReadKey();
            myThread.Stop(0); // stops the thread 0
        }
    }
}
```

Well, as you can see I'm not able right now to start threads using multiple parameters, but I didn't need to pass parameter to my thread.

Since I want to make everything clean, I accept any suggestion to improve this, also small suggestions for the code to make me able to pass one, two or more parameters and for cross-threading too (the `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThread = false;` alternative way - so using delegates with `Invoke()` or `BeginInvoke()`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't actually work as intended. You're using the `CancellationTokenSource` as a bool to decide whether to re-invoke the callback. That's **not** *stopping a thread*; that **is** *not re-invoking the callback when it returns*. The only reason why it appears to work for you is:

- Your test callback is very short. Try inserting a long-running callback.
- You print "Thread has been stopped successfully! Press any key to continue..." right after calling `Cancel()`. That statement is false; the only thing that has happened at that point is the `CancellationTokenSource` has been cancelled.

Other non-functional issues:

- The `CreatedThreads` list doesn't hold threads, it holds `CancellationTokenSource`s. Name the list appropriately.
- Why is `CreatedThreads` public? It seems like something you wouldn't want the class to expose. Make it private.
- This method is very strange:

> ```
> private int getLastIndex()
> {
>     int index = 0;
>     foreach (CancellationTokenSource item in CreatedThreads)
>     {
>         ++index;
>     }
>
>     return (index - 1);
> }
> ```

Why does it not just return `CreatedThreads.Count - 1` rather than iterating through the whole list? At that point there's no need for a method for it; `Start` can just do `int currentIndex = CurrentThreads.Count - 1;`

- It is very awkward to have the `Stop` method take an index of the thread to stop, especially when an index was not supplied to or returned from `Start`. How is the caller of the method to know what index their thread is?

Finally I assume the only reason why you are calling `Console` methods in the `CThread` class is because you're using it for testing. Otherwise you definitely should not be doing that.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding to `getLastIndex()` function, I figured it out it was trash, because I tried to use just the `Last()` function (as for Lists this function is available but it doesn't return an int, so I had some problems), not to use its `Count` property.Regarding to misinterpreting CancellationTokenSource with threads, OK, I will take care (I wanted just to do a "simulation", I know actually they aren't thread). Regarding to `that is not re-invoking the callback when it returns`, it actually is, just tested. Why wouldn't it work with long-running callback? What do you mean with long-run?

Comment: This is what's happening. You're calling `Cancel()` on the `CancellationTokenSource`. That does nothing apart from change that object's state; it has nothing to do with the callback you're running. The only way it is effecting the callback is inside a loop, by making you stop invoking the callback (`while (not cancelled) { invoke callback }`).  // ... continued...

Comment: ..continued... But if the callback takes 1 minute to execute, and you call `Stop()` right after `Start()`, the callback will not stop executing; after a minute it will return, and because the CTS was cancelled, it won't be invoked again; but you didn't stop the thread or the task being executed, you only stopped the loop from invoking the callback again. I assume you want the running callback to stop when you call `Stop`, not continue running for another 10 minutes or however long it takes to complete, otherwise I don't see the point of this class.

Comment: Re: long running, change your `printFunction` method to this: `for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }` and see what happens when you try to stop it.

Comment: you are right. What do you suggest me to do to stop waiting for that routine to finish?

Comment: I don't know what the best way is, though personally I would make any code which should be cancellable work with a CancellationToken - but that code would have to poll the token regularly to see if it should stop. If you want to just be able to execute any delegates, and stop them without cooperation of the code being executed, then the only way I can think of doing it is through creating a proper thread to run the callback and then calling `Abort()` on the thread through the `Stop()` method.

Comment: then the class is not clean anymore.

Comment: True, and I am definitely not suggesting that `Abort()` is the way to go - in fact I would advise against it. I am just saying what options you have, that I know of.